# How do I copy a folder and its contents (files/subdirectories) in Python with platform independent implementation

Tags: python-3.x, copy, directory

I need a function in python that lets me specify the source and destination paths for a folder and copies the source folder recursively into the destination folder. The implementation I am looking for needs to be platform independent

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You could use [shutil.copytree](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/shutil.html#shutil.copytree):

> shutil.copytree(src, dst, symlinks=False, ignore=None,
>   copy_function=copy2, ignore_dangling_symlinks=False)
>
> Recursively copy an entire directory tree rooted at src, returning the destination directory. The destination directory, named by dst,
>   must not already exist; it will be created as well as missing parent
>   directories. Permissions and times of directories are copied with
>   copystat(), individual files are copied using shutil.copy2().

---

```
import shutil
shutil.copytree(src, dst)
```