# Copy an entire folder from the Internet

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

I am developing a game which can download the new versions. When you click a button, the game downloads the files needed in the new version.

At the moment, I am using a website where I stock all the files to download, and a `.txt` file which says where to put each file.

Now I tend to add more and more files, and it could be really easier for me to put all the added files in the right file tree structure on the Internet, then merge those folders in the game folder on the user PC.

I know [how to move entire folder and its subfolders](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27592258), but how can I download directly the file tree in the right tree?

I am using `urllib` at the moment, but maybe another module could do the job as well.

Comment: HTTP doesn't natively support 'directory listings' so this would be quite a difficult approach. Why don't you just use an archive format like gzip and extract it over your folder? That way there's only one file to download and it includes a directory tree.

Comment: Where is your code to show what you have tried so far? "Does somebody know how to solve my problem?" is not even trying. There is little someone can do for you except what Yash Makan did for you, which is to do the work for you.

Comment: I didn't post code because I didn't write any. I may be wrong, but I think that "what did you try" isn't the right question here. Better ask "where did you search" because the question isn't about programming skills, but about knowledge around internet file managment. Yash Makan didn't *write code for me*, he made me know about something I didn't know. I don't know if you can understand, I'm not English and I'm struggling to find the right words.

Comment: Anyways I was like 150 rep when I posted this question, and I think I learned a bit since then. This question has been answered, and I would consider it as closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the files in .zip format and extract them in the required path from the .txt. Here is the code below to achieve the same.

```
import requests, zipfile, io
r = requests.get("https://codeload.github.com/fogleman/Minecraft/zip/master")
z = zipfile.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(r.content))
z.extractall("path")
```

OR

```
import zipfile, urllib.request, shutil

url = 'https://codeload.github.com/fogleman/Minecraft/zip/master'
file_name = 'myzip.zip'

with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as response, open(file_name, 'wb') as out_file:
    shutil.copyfileobj(response, out_file)
    with zipfile.ZipFile(file_name) as zf:
        zf.extractall()
```

Comment: Thank you. Are all of those modules in the standard library?

Comment: @D-00 Yes all are in the standard library and comes pre-installed with python

Comment: Ok, I thought requests wasn't in the Standard library. I use Python 3.8.

Comment: Requests is not part of the standard library however it can be installed with `pip install requests`

Comment: Ok I think I'll use urllib instead of requests because I want to avoid to download modules if I can.